# php unreasonable error No database selected but i select database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');//mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname);
mysql_select_db('stat');

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
else 
echo "yes\n";

$sql = "INSERT INTO stat VALUES (NULL, \'2012-09-02\', \'1000\')";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

DB was selected, but msql.error() return "No database selected" !
why?

Comment: Please don't use any mysq_* functions as they are deprecated. Consider using [PDO](http://be1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: You are using `mysqli_connect_errno` and `mysql_*` functions, as @juergend says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code try this.

```
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("!Server");

mysql_select_db('stat',$con) or die("!db");

$sql = "INSERT INTO stat VALUES (NULL,'2012-09-02','1000')";

$result2 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: you are not quite able to connect to your database check your database name.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions post the example using `mysqli_*` or `PDO` functions

Answer (score 2):

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","stat");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO stat(column1, column2, column3)
VALUES (NULL, \'2012-09-02\', \'1000\')");
```